# NonConfiguredNavigationToSharedType error from EF Core when upgrading to .NET 5

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-5

I just tested upgrading a project from .NET Core 3.1 to .NET 5. But I encountered the following error when the DbContext is used:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The navigation 'MyDatabaseModel.SomeProperty' must be configured in 'OnModelCreating' with an explicit name for the target shared type entity type, or excluded by calling 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore'.

The problem is that I don't understand what this error message is trying to tell me. The property it complains about is defined like this:

```
[Column("some_property", TypeName = "jsonb")]
public JsonDocument _someProperty { get; set; }

public Dictionary<string, object> SomeProperty
{
    get
    {
        // the JsonDocument is converted to the Dictionary here
    }
}
```

The data is stored in the database as a JSONB column. There is some custom code to convert it into the `Dictionary<string, object>` type the application expected here.

But this isn't a navigation property like the error message claims, it doesn't link to any oder database entitites. I don't understand what the "target shared type entity type" is supposed to be. Searching for this specific error message also doesn't provide any clues, I couldn't find anyone else running into this issue, only where the error string is defined in .NET.

What exactly is EF Core trying to tell me here, what is the actual problem it complains about? And how would I apply the solutions it suggests, configuring this in OnModelCreating or ignoring it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configure the property so that EF ignores it, like -

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<SomeModel>().Ignore(p => p.SomeProperty);
}
```

Or, you can do the same thing declaratively by adding the `[NotMapped]` attribute like -

```
[NotMapped]
public Dictionary<string, object> SomeProperty
{
    get
    {
        // the JsonDocument is converted to the Dictionary here
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn''t actually answer OP's question

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it'll be fixed later. For now - just define class:

```
public class SomePropertyType: Dictionary<string, object>{}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Unlike the answer selected, this actually fixed the problem for me. In .netcore 3.1 the jsonb type was able to be converted without error to dictionary. Now in 6.0 it appears to need a non-generic type in order for it to work.